# Process streams one by one and not in paralllel

Tags: apache-flink

Flink beginner - Need to process datastreams one after another and not in parallel

I have one datastream per file.

I need to maintain order of processing.But streams are all processed in parallel.Datasets did not help either.
suggestions??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use *org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.source.ContinuousFileMonitoringFunction* in Flink, which monitors files and forward file splits downstream in order of modification time; To achieve sequential file processing, you can make the parallelism of downstream to 1, which is a little tricky;
Or you can implement your own custom SourceFunction, which forwards file content in your desired order.

Comment: Thanks @Victor.. that is very useful information ..by the way am not reading directly from source function rather the data is sent via kafka to another job and sequential processing is done there.Do you still think this approach is sufficient or should it be handled at kafka end?And I have one topic per file.

Comment: I'm a little confused, if you are consuming data from Kafka, how do you tell the processing is done, since Kafka source is infinite.

Comment: I have added  a custom "EOF" record added at the end of every file while reading

Comment: OK, maybe you can send your file data to a kafka topic sequentially with only one partition (because data across different partitions are not ordered), and add your custom "EOF" between files.

Comment: Thanks am yet to check that.And one more clarification.can we use StreamExecutionEnvironment within a flatmap or process function.It doesn't work for me.The scenario is like as we read through a file,fetch a value,query redis using that value as key and get those records.To fetch from redis I need a datastream and to create that I need a env variable within faltmap.How can we do this?Any other option?

Comment: Yes, you may not access `StreamExecutionEnvironment` within flatmap function (and other functions as well, since these functions run in TaskManagers). But you can create your own `RichFlatMapFunction`, initialize a redis client with `open` method, and use that to query redis within `flatMap` method.